# Oracle hierarchical query - combine results

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

Given a table:

```
Old_ID  New_ID
A       B
B       C
```

Multiple ID changes can form a chain A -> B -> C. I can do a hierarchical query.

```
SELECT Old_ID, New_ID from mytable
CONNECT BY PRIOR New_ID = Old_ID
```

Since C is the valid new ID for both A and B, the result I'd like to get is:

```
Old_ID  New_ID
A       C
B       C
```

So map all old IDs to the latest new ID in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `CONNECT_BY_ROOT( old_id )`, to get the start of the hierarchy, and `WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1`, to find the last item in the hierarchy:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b50463/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table( Old_ID, New_ID ) As
SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( old_id ) AS old_id,
       new_id
FROM   your_table
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR New_ID = Old_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b50463/1/0)**:

```
| OLD_ID | NEW_ID |
|--------|--------|
|      A |      C |
|      B |      C |
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. If I run your query without the predicate (CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1) against your table, I get three rows. If I do the same against my table (which in fact is a little more complicated), I get two rows. I wonder if there's difference between 12c and 11g (Fiddle).

Comment: @Rubio Without being able to see what you are doing it is impossible to say why you get 2 rows. You can use `SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( old_id ) AS root_id, old_id, new_id, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF FROM your_table CONNECT BY PRIOR New_id = Old_ID` to show you the rows it is processing and whether it is a leaf but 3 rows is correct: `root: A, old: A, new: B` is not a leaf of the hierarchy but if you descend the hierarchy one level (`root: A, old: B, new: C`) and if you start from `B` (`root: B, old: B, new: C`) then these are leaves as `C` had no descendants.

Comment: I recreated your sample in a temp table in my DB and your solution definitely works. There must be something funky in my data.

Comment: Can you think of a way to group by id chain or give a common identifier to rows that form a chain?